# site is not showing responsivness

Tags: html, css

i was trying to get them in grids divided on 3 column but they are not showing responsiveness they are coming in a list like format

```
<div class="row">
  <section id="features">

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle  fa-4x circle"></i>
      <h3 class='circleh'>Easy to use.</h3>
      <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <i class="fas fa-bullseye col-lg-4 fa-4x bullseye"></i>
      <h3 class='bullseyeh'>Elite Clientele</h3>
      <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <i class="fas fa-heart col-lg-4 fa-4x heart"></i>
      <h3 class='hearth'>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
      <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: did you add css?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4?

Comment: Check in your browser console if bootstrap is loaded

Comment: along with that check "viewport" meta on head

Comment: yes i have added css and using bootstrap 4

Comment: yes bootstrap is loaded and working fine

Comment: should change features is parent div.. row is child @kira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `bootstrap 4` than you have to use below structure. In bootstrap 4 you have to  must `row` class as parent of `col-` classes.

```
<section id="features">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle  fa-4x circle"></i>
        <h3 class='circleh'>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-bullseye col-lg-4 fa-4x bullseye"></i>
        <h3 class='bullseyeh'>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-heart col-lg-4 fa-4x heart"></i>
        <h3 class='hearth'>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the section tag added inside of the row. this will break the default behavior of the grid system. and make sure to add stylesheet and scripts in the html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="features">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-4">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle  fa-4x circle"></i>
      <h3 class='circleh'>Easy to use.</h3>
      <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <i class="fas fa-bullseye col-lg-4 fa-4x bullseye"></i>
      <h3 class='bullseyeh'>Elite Clientele</h3>
      <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <i class="fas fa-heart col-lg-4 fa-4x heart"></i>
      <h3 class='hearth'>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
      <p style='color:#8f8f8f'>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
    </div>


</div>
</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you have any css?
and if not, create a css file and link it in, or create a style tag in the HTML doc.

Onece you have some sort of css file, type the following:

```
.row{
  column-count: 3;
}
```

And after that you should see the three div's devided to 3 columns